# RoR AWS-SDK Error when accessing bucket in Europe region

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, nameerror, bucket, aws-sdk

I am using latest aws-sdk for Ruby. My rake file contains following line to connect to S3 bucket:

```
require 'aws-sdk'
...
AWS.config(
  :access_key_id => 'xxxxx', 
  :secret_access_key => 'xxxxx'
)
s3 = AWS::S3.new
object = s3.buckets['bucket_in_ireland'].objects['data.csv']
```

When accessing an AWS S3 bucket in region **US** that works perfectly fine. But getting following error while accessing AWS S3 bucket in region **Ireland**:

```
AWS::S3::Errorrs::PermanentRedirect: The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.
```

From Google I could find two solutions:

1. Put `AWS::S3::DEFAULT_HOST.replace "s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com"` at the bottom of **environment.rb**
2. Set `:s3_host_name => 's3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com'` for **paperclip** default settings

When I placed the line mentioned in (1) at the bottom of **environment.rb**, the error message changed to following:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant AWS::S3::DEFAULT_HOST
```

Then I tried (2) by updating following code in **production.rb** but that didn't help.

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  :storage => :s3,
  :s3_credentials => {
    :bucket => ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
    :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
    :s3_host_name => 's3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com'
  }
}
```

**Note:** Also tried to apply this fix [https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/issues/510] but nothing really changed after modifications in **environment.rb**, but nothing work.

Any help please...

Answer (score 0):

Setting **s3_endpoint** to AWS config solved the issue for me.

```
  AWS.config(
    :access_key_id => 'xxxx', 
    :secret_access_key => 'xxxx',
    :s3_endpoint => 's3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com'
  )
```